# NoSQL Data Storage + K-V Cache

Tags: redis, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I am building a system stores the promotion activities and bunch of promotion meta data.

At the beginning, the data looks like:
promotion_name, promotion_content, promotion_location.
And I will query the data with `promotion_name` + `promotion_location`

In the future, there could be extra query attributes associated with the new promotion events like `promotion_category`... etc. I plan to store the data in a NoSQL database like DynamoDB, so I do not need to migrate the table schema with any extra attributes.

I have multiple data pipelines fetching the promotion information. To make the query efficient, would it make sense to concatenate all the reference fields as key (ex: `promotion_location` + `promotion_category` + `promotion_name`) and store them to another K-V cache. Or should I keep adding indexes to the new field (like `promotion_category`) in DynamoDB?

There're probably going to be at most 10 ~ 20 new fields in the future. Is it possible that DynamoDB can store them as 2nd index when a new field being detected? Or it's easy to just implement key composition logic in backend and store in another cache.

Comment: cache and index are not the same thing. Do you need to access the records by 20 different fields? The number of indexes in DynamoDB is designed for common use cases.

Comment: For different use cases, I will need to access the records with 3 ~ 4 fields in different combination. I am wondering should be index all the fields or combine them to a single key and save it.

Comment: The number 3-4 is exactly the common use case and within the limit of the number of indexes (local secondary index) that you add to a dynmaoDB table. Please note that you can add an index when you find the need for it, or remove an index if nobody uses it.